# Correct usage of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to restrict to certain device models?

Tags: iphone

is it necesaary to mention UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in info.plist

and lets say my app will run on all 3g,3gs and 4, ipad  and what should be the info in my UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities??

right now i just did this

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
 <string>telephony</string>
 <string>gps</string>
  <string>location-services</string>
</array>
```

plz help thanks

Comment: Why are you restricting to these devices in the first place? Is it because your app requires these things? Or it doesn't perform well on older devices and you want to prevent people with those from buying it?

Comment: (Edited title. Please use more precise question titles.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to setup device-specific UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600787/is-it-possible-to-setup-device-specific-uirequireddevicecapabilities-in-info-pli)

Answer (score 1):

iPad doesnt have telephony so leave that out, iPod touches dont have gps so leave that out…

Your best bet is to remove all of these functions and do the checking in software.

Comment: how to do checking in sofwtare ple help

Comment: Read the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW15