# Is it possible to setup device-specific UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store, info.plist

So is it possible to setup device-specific UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist like UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities~ipod, UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities~ipad. The devices i'd like to support are: ipod 5+, iphone 4+, ipad 2+; Also is it possible to test those restrictions before posting app to appstore. Thanks. 
About Device-specific keys: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Comment: The question is why do you only want to support those devices.

Comment: ipod 4 has lower memory than iphone 4 that's the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct usage of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to restrict to certain device models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751940/correct-usage-of-uirequireddevicecapabilities-to-restrict-to-certain-device-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you cant. you can only request **capabilities** - you can check the model at runtime only

that said, you can combine certain capabilities to exclude groups of device models

Comment: You mean I can't test it or I can't set device specific required capabilities?

Comment: not with the key, no. Later at RUNTIME you can check UIDevice.model